# jQuery Datepicker closes on click, IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2, with jQuery UI 1.7.1. I'm using a DatePicker attached to a text input field. It opens and renders fine in all browsers, and works perfectly in IE7, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. However, in IE6, when I click anywhere on it, it closes without performing any action. Also, none of the hover effects work (e.g. when hovering over the previous/next month buttons), so it looks like there's something over it that's preventing it from registering hover/click events. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried throwing in some debugging code on the hover/click event handlers?

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem using IE6.  If you link to a sample page, perhaps you'll get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain the attachment to the text input is correct?

If so, another possibility is a conflict with a different javascript library. Are you using anything besides jQuery (eg mootools, script.aculo.us, etc.) on the page? Try creating a minimal example with just the datepicker.

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI's DatePicker without any problems in IE6.